# A component is changing a controlled input of type of text to be uncontrolled

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

Im getting an error warning of, A component is changing a controlled input of type text to be uncontrolled. And Im not so familiar wirh functional component because Im use to be in class. All I did was just:

Setting an initial state for my list:

```
const [list, setList] = 
useState({title: ' '})
```

Then setting the value of my title obj using onChange:

```
const setTitle =e=> 
{setList(e.target.value)}
```

And then getting the value of it using onChange

```
<input type='text onChange= 
{setTitle} value={list.title} 
palceholder="Add" />
```

I tried, setting the value of my input to value={list}, but my textbox's place holder displayin the [object] [Object]. Im super new here, kindly help me explain whats happening here so I might get the concept or idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

List state is supposed to be an object and when you update state on change event, you change it to be a string instead.

Update the state such that you are just updating the title key within the list object in state like below

```
const setTitle =e=>  {
    const value = e.target.value; // Remember to copy value into a variable since events are cleared by react
    setList(prev=> ({...prev, title: value}));
}
```

Comment: the list won't be the value, the property `title` inside of the list will.

Answer (score 0):

You're almost correct, but you're missing something:

```js
setTitle = e => {
  const title = e.target.value;
  setList(prevState => ({ ...prevState, title }));
}
```

You are saying the state is an object containing a title property so when you set it you have to set an object with the title that comes from the value as well :)

Answer (score 0):

To avoid this kind of error, its safely this:

```
<input type=text value={list} onChange={(e) => setList(e.target.value)} />
```